# change image src in php?

Tags: php

I beginner in php and I am making small project which will help me learn more php. any way on webserver I have uploaded pictures which in this format:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
```

and so on....

in the body of my page I have:

```
<?php
$imageNumber = 1;
?>
<img src="'$imageNumber'.'.jpg'">
```

why is this code is not working ?
also I want to create a function that every time the user click a button the `$imageNumber` get incremented by `1`

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber ?>.jpg">` would probably do it for you.

Comment: First you need Array on images, than calculate this array,
for each keyitem of array create template your 
<img src="<?php echo $val?; >".jpg alt="echo url " />

Answer (score 7):

You can only use PHP variables inside PHP tags.

```
<?php
   $imageNumber = 1;
   echo '<img src="'.$imageNumber.'.jpg'">';
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
   $imageNumber = 1;
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber ?>.jpg">
```

For the function, use javascript. jQuery would be simplest, but I've included a raw version too:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
     <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

  <img id="the_image" src="1.jpg">

  <input type="button" id="the_button" value="change" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
     var maxNumImages = 5;
     // for the function, use javascript. jQuery would be simplest:
     jQuery(function($) {

        $('#the_button').click(function() {
           var num = ($('#the_image').attr('src').match(/(\d+).jpg$/)||[false])[1];
           if( num !== false ) {
              if( num == maxNumImages ) { num = 0; }
              $('#the_image').attr('src', (++num)+'.jpg');
           }
        });

     });
  </script>

  <img id="the_image2" src="1.jpg">

  <input type="button" id="the_button2" value="change" />

  <script>
     // or in old fashioned (i.e. boring,sad,pathetic,vanilla) js:
     var maxNumImages = 5;
     var button = document.getElementById('the_button2');
     button.onclick = function() {
        var image  = document.getElementById('the_image2');
        console.log(image.src);
        var num = (image.src.match(/(\d+).jpg$/)||[false])[1];
        console.log(num);
        if( num !== false ) {
           if( num == maxNumImages ) { num = 0; }
           image.src = (++num)+'.jpg';
        }
     }
  </script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: as others have stated, you would do the button in javascript

Comment: Don't forget to point the first <script> to a jQuery installation :)

Comment: @kato I tried to use the code, the image code is working, but when I click the button change the image does not change or the url of the page.

Comment: Well I'd like to help, but jsfiddle is down today, so there can be no coding :) Alright, let me have a look; are you using the jQuery or the js version?

Comment: Looks like I mistakenly put in \D instead of \d; le sigh; updating now :) Also, ++num will work better than num++; I'll post a full working example in just a min

Comment: There you go, a completely functional example (just provide your own kittens! or yanno, cute puppy images if you prefer)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is not your only code??

- You forget an `echo` (or `print`)
- Strange single/dubbel quotes
- strange dot

You are searching for something like:

```
<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber; ?>.jpg">
```

And to increase a number use ++

```
$i = 0;
echo ++$i; // echo's 1 (increase the number and print it)
echo $i++; // echo's 1 (print it and then increase the number)
echo $i; // echo's 2 (print the number)
```

---

And for a click on a button you can better use JS:

```
<img src="1.jpg" id="img-id">
<button id="increaseImg">Increase img</button>

<script>
  var img = document.getElementById('img-id'), // get the img tag
      btn = document.getElementById('increaseImg'), // get the button tag
      i = 1; // the number

  btn.onclick = function() {
    img.src = ++i + '.jpg'; // each click increase i and change the img src
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

$variables don't magically work outside of a PHP code block.

The following approaches would do what you're trying to do:

```
<?php
$imageNumber = 1;
echo '<img src="' . $imageNumber . '.jpg">';
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
$imageNumber = 1;
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber; ?>.jpg">
```

Comment: Please don't jump in with a non-answer having no explanation or code samples to be the 1st answerer. It isn't helpful.

Comment: @halfer Because it had no content other than the first sentence until it was edited following a bunch of downvotes.

Comment: @halfer I didn't include the code samples until after I started getting downvotes.  I think people thought "magically" was too snarky.  Really just meant it as a reference to the way PHP parses variables inside double-quotes, but whatever...

Comment: @Michael That wasn't the intention.  I didn't realize until after it started getting downvoted that a code sample would be needed.

Comment: @Michael - thanks. Strange, I don't see any note to show it's been edited, but ah well.

Comment: @Farray - code samples aren't always required, but they're often the best way to answer :)

Comment: @halfer A couple of minutes have to pass between initially answering and editing for the "Edited" to appear. There's a grace period where they expect a few edits, I think.

Comment: @halfer True, but my original 1-line answer did answer the actual question.  "Why is this not working?" ... "Because it's not in a PHP code block."  Give a man a PHP vs show a man to PHP...  ;)

Comment: @Michael With how fast those downvotes came, I was welllllllll within the grace period. Fun times...

Comment: @Farray - odd, that. There have been a few occasions where I've withheld answers because I've felt a [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) was at work. I've never been downvoted for it, afaik.

Comment: @Michael One last thing...  the comment thread on Kato's answer is exactly why I don't always care to automatically include code samples.  Instead of just answering the question, Kato is now crafting a full solution for the asker, and the response is "original problem is fixed, now I have another problem".  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem

Comment: @halfer We're on the same page (hey -  a different Help Vamp link?).  I think it was just my word choice...

Comment: @Farray When the OP comes back with _now I have a different problem_ the appropriate response is, due to the atomic nature of questions on Stack Exchange, _"Then please submit a new question."_

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$imageNumber = 1;
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber; ?>.jpg" />
```

OR

```
<?php
$imageNumber = 1;
echo "<img src='$imageNumber.jpg' />";
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$imageNumber = 1;
echo '<img src="' . $imageNumber . '.jpg" />';
?>
```

Don't use PHP for the click button thing.  Use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$imageNumber = 1;
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber;?>.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  PHP variables will only be parsed inside the php tags.

```
<?php
$imageNumber = 1;
echo "<img src=\"{$imageNumber}.jpg\">";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the variable $imageNumber properly, however you then need to output it with echo:

```
<?php
$imageNumber = 1;
?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber; ?>.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP code only works *inside* the PHP opening and closing tags (`<?php ?>`).

The following block works:

```
<?php

$imageNumber = 1;

?>
<img src="<?php echo $imageNumber; ?>.jpg" />
```

Everything inside the PHP tags will be interpreted by PHP, the rest remains unaffected.
With the line `<?php echo $imageNumber; ?>`, PHP will **echo** ('send to the browser') the variable $imageNumber. Thus, the browser the receives this:

```
<img src="1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <img src="<?PHP echo $imageNumber ?>.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need Array on images, than calculate this array,
for each keyitem of array create template your 
".jpg alt="echo url " />

`

```
$images= array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");

shuffle($images);
foreach ($images as $img) {
    echo "<img src='imagesDirectory/$img.jpg'> <br>";
}
```

`