# how can I change the src of an image according to the value inside a tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<div class="card-body border-0">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="icons/Termo.png" alt="">
</div>

<td>
    <?php echo $value_termo ?>
</td>
```

I have this code, with a value that comes from a txt file, this value returns a boolean, if it is true, I need to change the image.

how can I do this?

Comment: Create a variable and pass the variable to src. And whenever you need change the value of the variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change image src in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218744/change-image-src-in-php)

Comment: In which language? Your question has both javascript and PHP tags.  You could for example concatenate this variable right in the middle of your src attribute. Please show us your attempt at achieving what you describe

Comment: Shouldn't you evealuate the boolean in PHP if it is PHP returning the boolean?

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand what you are expecting exactly.

assuming this is

```
 <div class="card-body border-0">
      <?php if(is_bool($value_termo)=== true){?>
           <img class="img-fluid" src="alternate_image_path" alt="">
      <?php }else { ?>
           <img class="img-fluid" src="icons/Termo.png" alt="">
      <?php } ?>
  </div>

  <td>
        <?php echo $value_termo; ?>
  </td>
```

Comment: ***value that comes from a txt file, this value returns a boolean, if it is true, I need to change the image.*** => what if `if(!empty($value_termo))` returns ***false***, it would not be empty however it would be *false*. Perhaps changing the conditional to also include evaluation for true/false?

Comment: ok... plz check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
<div class="card-body border-0">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="<?= $value_termo ? 'icons/True.png' : 'icons/Termo.png' ?>" alt="">
</div>

<td>
    <?php echo $value_termo ?>
</td>
```